# Shortest way to generate 12 repeated characters in JavaScript

Tags: tips, javascript

```
'---------'
'-'.repeat(9) // longer!

'------------'
(x='----')+x+x
'-'.repeat(12) // same length
```

Is there any cleverer way of generating strings of 12 repeated characters in JavaScript?

Comment: Don't think so but depending on the challenge you may be able to golf multiple runs to save bytes using e.g. RLE

Comment: For the special case of commas you can do `Array(12)+''`, which is shorter than the literal starting at 11 commas and then remains shorter than `repeat`.

Comment: Cool - how often do you need a string of commas?

Comment: @SteveBennett sometimes you only care about the string length and not the actual character, and many PPCG challenges allow you to use some ASCII character of your choice for output.

Comment: If you're going to be reusing repeat, you can alias it.

Comment: If you don't really need 12 identical characters but rather a 12-character string, you can also do `1e11+''`.

Comment: I'm not sure about javascript, but in python you can do `'-'*12`

Comment: Yeah, that's awesome but doesn't work in JS.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, after what seems an eternity of searching documentation, I can't seem find any solution that will work with the 12-character constraint and generate for any given character given. However, there are a few neat tricks one can do to save some bytes for specific cases:

- `1eL-1+''` will give a string, filled with `9`s, of *L* length.
- `''.padEnd(L)` will give a string, filled with spaces, of *L* length. It's only useful when *L* > 10, otherwise it's too long. This one can be immediately chained with a function.
- `N/9+''` will give a string, starting with `0.` then followed by a bunch of `N`s. This does not work when *N* < 1 or *N* > 8, and the result obviously does not contain the same characters the whole way, but pretty close and pretty short.
- [`Array(L)+''`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123191/tip-short-way-to-generate-up-to-12-repeated-characters-in-javascript#comment302215_123191) will give a string, filled with commas, of length *L* - 1.

Comment: Along the lines of your `1/3+''` tip, you can repeat a digit D (except 0 and 9) a bunch of times similarly with `D/9+''`.

Comment: `Array(L)+''` gives `L-1` length, right?

Comment: Which means that for L=13, the code is 12 characters and the output is 12 characters, so the same as `','.repeat(12)`